# UWP with WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, win-universal-app

I'm try to create the main `UWP` app to link with the service by perform this step

1.Create `Blank App` of `UWP`

2.Create `Window Service Application` (Create in the solution now the solution will have 2 projects)

3.In the reference in main application Add service reference

4.Discover and then change name of to be something (This time I user ToDoService)

5.Create the code to call in main PS. I'm using the button that create before

```
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ToDoService.Service1Client client = new ToDoService.Service1Client();
        MessageDialog x = new MessageDialog(client.GetDataAsync(10).Result);
        client.CloseAsync();
        x.ShowAsync();
    }
```

When I run this application is OK until I click on the button and it's crash anyone know what is the problem with it

Comment: Have you tried to await on the async method?

Comment: Cannot reproduce your problem. I can run successfully as [picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pbvLt.png) shows .Which error was thrown when crash?  Please try to build your WCF application and rerun.

Comment: @Sunteen I can run it on local machine successfully but not in the real device (I use window phone and run on it)

Comment: Where is the service running when you deploy the app to the real device? Still on your development machine or have you published it somewhere? Did you set the endpoint address of the client in the app correctly?

Comment: And  for your second  step, create Window Service Application, do you means just create a WCF Service Application or create a Windows Service and hosted the WCF Service?

Comment: @DamirArh I'm not quite sure about the step but I'm only create all code the following on the PC and connect the pc with window phone an debug it  on the device and it's crash

Comment: @Sunteen I'm just create it and I'm add the reference to the main code in step3 but I'm not sure is it require to host since I create or not if it is require please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can run it on local machine successfully but not in the real device (I use window phone and run on it)

You can connect to WCF service in your local PC machine, that's because your local WCF service application default hosed by **[IIS Express](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-express-overview)** and have a default service address like http://localhost:.... So your client in local machine off course can invoke the WCF service  deployed in local machine correctly by add the default address. But when you run your client on the real windows phone device,your WCF service doesn' deploy on your device , how your client connect to the WCF service by a localhost address?

If you want to invoke the WCF service correctly on your real device, you can [publish](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924407(v=vs.110).aspx) the WCF service and set the right endpoint address of the client in the app and please make sure that your firewall does not block the service port

Comment: May I ask something How do I can set the right endpoint address of the client in the app

Comment: The endpoint address is  what the address of your WCF deployed. For example I set the address as the [picture] (http://i.stack.imgur.com/V7OcB.png) ! shows , because I deployed my wcf service in server 10.168.174.97. This question we talk about why it failed to connect wcf service, if you still have new questions such as how to deploy a wcf service,please to do some new learning or open new thread for help.